# Extracting application's data from Linux

Tags: linux, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a machine learning project for classifying the applications user has used during a particular session on his pc .The OS i am working on is Linux and for the start i an only classifying the two aplications web browser and text editor .I need to extract the data of these application when user is using them for extracting features so later it can be use for making my model . Can any one tell me how can i do that  . How can i fetch information from which i can extract some good features such as (application's name , id , start time , directory , end time etc) for classification of applications user used during any session .

Comment: There is the `top` command that you could get a bunch of data from. Not sure if that's enough for your purposes.